# What is the syntax for commenting out lines in logrotate config files?

Tags: 16.04, logrotate

Not sure if this is possible at all.

And what about empty lines?

*Update:*

Testing the config with

```
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

returns

```
error: /etc/logrotate.d/apache2:1 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)
```

for every empty line in the config file.

Original question about comment syntax is answered, though.

*Update 2*: This config now seems to work for me (note that it restarts apache after rotation):

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482773/apache-and-logrotate-configuration
    su root adm
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    create 640 root adm
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845752/logrotate-suffix-dateext-rotate
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d.log
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        systemctl restart apache2 || true
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
man logrotate
```

> Note that comments may appear anywhere in the config file as long as the
>          first non-whitespace character on the line is a #.

Comment: Hm ok thanks, I guess I was confused by the error I was getting, which I thought was because of my hash - error: /etc/logrotate.d/apache2:1 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes). Will accept as soon as I get the config working.

Comment: try `sudo logrotate -v confName` it might help you diagnose the problem...

Comment: I am running `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/apache2` as root to check my config, which got me the error.

Comment: My logrotate file would NOT tolerate any comments.  But I'm on RedHat EL7.

Comment: Examples are always helpful